# Can this question be opened, or be changed to be reopenable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[How can I prepare for creatures with damage resistances or damage immunities?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120875/how-can-i-prepare-for-creatures-with-damage-resistances-or-damage-immunities)

I saw a lot of questions floating around the Stack about damage Immunities and Resistances and troubles therein for players (Lycanthropes, and Puddings, and Ooze, oh my!). I hoped to create a unifying question so that we could stop dealing with all of these ad-hoc things and just point to a single answer (as the answers are all usually the same sort of "prepare better, know your enemy").

The inspiration was another one-stop-shop question for forced movement, provided by Rubiksmoose: [Can I trigger an Opportunity Attack by forcing an opponent to move out of my reach?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120959/can-i-trigger-an-opportunity-attack-by-forcing-an-opponent-to-move-out-of-my-rea)

**Can my question either be reopened as-is, or is there something that we can do to make it Stackable, while also keeping my original intent?**

Comment: If your intent was to make a canonical answer, why didn't you answer your own question?

Comment: @icyfire I didn't know I was supposed to.

Comment: You don't have to, it just seems like it would make sense for a canonical question

Comment: I voted to reopen, also.

Answer (score 10):

So here's the problem with this.

1. Rubiksmoose ran afoul of this too, and really needed to have gathered feedback and consensus on meta before doing it.  As do you. See previous discussion about the question you link here: [Forced movement and OA duplicates](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/forced-movement-and-oa-duplicates)
2. "Canonical answers" are tricky things.  They are usually good if a problem space is pretty tightly scoped. "Does any kind of forced movement trigger OAs" is tightly scoped.  "What about forced movement from A?  From B?  From C?"  But the question you've asked has potential "too broad" issues on its face.  "What are all the ways to hurt something that has damage immunity" is in a sense "list every single way of hurting something in the game besides hitting it with the specific thing it's immune to." And in D&D, there's a crap-ton of ways of hurting something, yeah?
   The question vaguely hints that maybe it's just talking about martial characters but even martials can use magic, and since you say immunity and resistance, even "just hit it harder" is an option. You're in a party so "fend them off while the others kill them" is an option.

In the end this is a case where a specific case may well not be answered by the "canonical".  A barbarian, rogue, or bard would certainly use different coping mechanisms.  At level 1 'carry a couple weapons' is a good answer, at high levels there are many many ways to accomplish it.

Comment: Would narrowing it down to martial characters help tighten the scope?

Comment: @goodguy5 I think it certainly would help, but still not enough. Maybe narrowing it down to low levels as well, as at higher levels this usually ceases to be a problem as you have many **mechanical** options directly given by your features, feats and magical items.

Comment: Yeah, I think if you limited it to "no magic" or something it might be tenable (not "by class").  But in the end I'm not sure these are crying out for a canonical solution, unless all the original questions have the same scope.